# How to customize iPhone UITabBarController selected icon, background?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uikit

In the UITabBarController I have implemented.. (the standard one).. when an item is selected, it has an opaque grey square background behind the item. Is there a way to change the colour and opacity of that square?
Would prefer if I don't have to use an external API or hack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, there is no documented way of changing view properties of UITabBar, without doing some kind of hacks like subclassing UITabBar and putting colorful top layer that would became a tint . You will most likely need to create your own tab bar using UIButtons.

Comment: Thanks Cyprian! Was hoping to not have to do that :)